# How to iterate the TValue type property in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

> I need to iterate the TValue type property in Blazor.
>
> Component Tag as MYComponent.

```
<select>
@foreach (var item in this.Value(TValue))
        {
            <option selected value=@item></option>
        }
</select>

@code {
public class MYComponent {
           public TValue Value {get;set;}    
           private string[] MyValue = new string[] {"Value1", "Value2"};
}
}
```

Comment: What is `TValue` ? Where it's defined ?

Comment: Why do you use it as function ?

Comment: Tvalue is defined in top of the razor page   @typeparam TValue;

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code please.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, you can achieve it by using reflexion :

```cs
@foreach (var item in GetProperties(TValue))
{
   <option selected value=@item></option>
}
</select>
@code {
    public class MYComponent 
    {
        public TValue Value {get;set;}    
        private string[] MyValue = new string[] {"Value1", "Value2"};
        public IEnumerable<string> GetProperties()
        {
              return typeof(TValue).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: currently not working above answer

Retrun the below values

typeof(TValue).GetProperties()

{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[7]}
    [0]: {Int32 Length}
    [1]: {Int64 LongLength}
    [2]: {Int32 Rank}
    [3]: {System.Object SyncRoot}
    [4]: {Boolean IsReadOnly}
    [5]: {Boolean IsFixedSize}
    [6]: {Boolean IsSynchronized}

Comment: Hi @agua from mars